# Why does OpenUrl() is not being called in iOS 13 but it does in iOS 12.(Xamarin.ios)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

We are working in xamarin.ios native app development. We have implemented OAuth redirect and implement OpenUrl() in AppDelegate class. it is working in iOS 12 but does not working is iOS 13 or later version both real device and simulator.

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // Convert iOS NSUrl to C#/netxf/BCL System.Uri - common API
            var uri_netfx = new Uri(url.AbsoluteString);

            clsXamrinAuthSample.Auth.OnPageLoading(uri_netfx);

            return true;
        }
```

we need some help.

Comment: Because in iOS 13 this functionality is moved to the Scene Delegate.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented OpenUrlContexts() in Scene Delegate and being called also but I am unable to access Url property. Please check my code below.

`[Export("scene:openURLContexts:")]
       public void OpenUrlContexts(UIScene scene, NSSet<UIOpenUrlContext> urlContexts)
            {
           
            foreach (var urlContextData in urlContexts)
                {
               
                 var urlString = urlContextData.Url;
             
                  clsXamrinAuthSample.Auth.OnPageLoading(urlString);
                } 
            }`

Comment: @SumitMishra Hi , have you solved it ? If answer be helpful , remember to mark it when you have time :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From iOS 13 , you need to detail with openUrl in `SceneDelegate.cs` file , writing code in `OpenUrlContexts` method .

> I am unable to access Url property.

About accessing `Url` proerty , you can get it from `AnyObject` element as follow .

```
[Export("scene:openURLContexts:")] 
public void OpenUrlContexts(UIScene scene, NSSet<UIOpenUrlContext> urlContexts) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("URL property =====" + urlContexts.AnyObject.Url);
    var urlString = urlContexts.AnyObject.Url;
    if( urlString.Equals("wide://"))
    {
        // Run code 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no SceneDelegate.cs file in my project. Do I need to add it myself? How?

Comment: @Rugbrød You need to add it manually . Have a look at this discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783842/window-makekeyandvisible-is-not-showing-new-window-in-ios-13-and-above-os/61790376#61790376 . If answer be helpful , remember to vote up it .

Comment: @Rugbrød Hi, it just works for Xamarin iOS project .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT In a Xamarin.Forms project, adding the new AppDelegate as above does not have a reference to LoadApplication or base.FinishedLaunching.

Comment: @Xamtastic Hi, you need to make sure that the new AppDelegate inherit form `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks, however I have since tried that, and it doesn't work, nor is there a pattern published by Microsoft that shows it in action. I have both the inheritance that you mention, and ScreenDelegate, but there is alot more to be wired (eg the Window) and whatever pattern I use to get the app running normally, the click to open the url using the above code does not work. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Xamtastic Hi, whether your solution is Xamarin.iOS? You could create a new question in SO to explain it with detailed information.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks, I've raised a new question here (complete with code): https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13786